# My LG G2 phone won't receive texts

Tags: sms, lg-g2

I recently switched from a iPhone to an LG G2 and now my phone won't receive texts. But it is sending them just fine.

Comment: Do you have the correct APN settings?

Answer (score 0):

Ask your network provider. It seems like it can't be a phone defect, just go to customer service and it should go alright

Answer (score 0):

the test messages might be going to your iphone. go to apple De-registration website and unregister your number off of imessage.